# convert HH:MM:SS.MS to seconds using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have a database where time is stored as `NVARCHAR(14)`.  An example of what I see when I query a specific user's time is 00:08:45.68.

What I want to do is convert this value of 0 hours, 8 minutes, 45 seconds and 68 milliseconds to a value of 526 seconds.  Greater than or equal to 50 milliseconds is rounded up.

I also have stored values where no milliseconds are captured, e.g. 98:40:12.  There are many records that have more than 24 hours of time stored, both with millseconds (97:18:59.32) and without (98:40:12).

I see lots of queries to convert seconds to `HH:MM:SS.MS`, but none the other way around.  I also see many queries that include dates, but I do not have a date stored with the time.

Hopefully I am being clear.

I tried the following:

```
(DATEPART(hh, trntime.time1) * 60 * 60) + (DATEPART(MI, trntime.time1) * 60) + DATEPART(s, trntime.time1) AS 'Calc_time1_Secs'
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any hour value > 24 is not really usable with the `TIME` type. As all but the first field are fixed length you could:

```
;with T(f) as (select '97:18:59.32')

select 
    (LEFT(f, CHARINDEX(':', f) - 1)  * 60 * 60)
    + (SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX(':', f) + 1, 2) * 60)
    + SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX(':', f) + 4, 2)
    + CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX(':', f) + 7, LEN(f)) >= 50) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
from T
```

Or

```
select 
    (LEFT(f, CHARINDEX(':', f) - 1)  * 60 * 60) 
    + CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, '00' 
    + (SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX(':', f), LEN(f)))) / 1000.0, 0) AS INT)
from T
```

Comment: I used your 2nd option and it appears to be working perfectly.  I just need time to do a detailed reconciliation now.  I thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  Also, I will try the first query as soon as I can.  I

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24417/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE trntime
    ([time1] NVARCHAR(14))
;

INSERT INTO trntime
    ([time1])
VALUES
    ('00:08:45.68'),
    ('97:18:59.32'),
    ('97:18:59.52'),
    ('98:40:12')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (hour*60*60) + 
       (DATEPART(MI, minutes) * 60) + 
       DATEPART(S, minutes) + 
       ROUND(DATEPART(MS, minutes)/1000.0,0) AS 'Calc_time1_Secs'
FROM (SELECT LEFT(time1,2) AS 'hour', 
      '00' + RIGHT(time1,LEN(time1)-2) AS 'minutes'
      FROM trntime) AS Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24417/1/0)**:

```
| CALC_TIME1_SECS |
|-----------------|
|             526 |
|          350339 |
|          350340 |
|          355212 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT (LEFT(time1,2)*60*60) +
       ROUND(DATEDIFF(MS, 0, '00' + RIGHT(time1,LEN(time1)-2))/1000.0,0)
        AS 'Calc_time1_Secs'
FROM trntime
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24417/1/1)**:

```
| CALC_TIME1_SECS |
|-----------------|
|             526 |
|          350339 |
|          350340 |
|          355212 |
```

Comment: Thanks as well!  I will try both of these once I do my reconciliation.

Answer (score 0):

First, normalise the time by adding 0 milliseconds if they are absent, then replace colon with full stop and use `parsename()`, since this will always have exactly 4 parts:

```
declare @t table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    TimeSec nvarchar(14) not null
);

insert into @t (TimeSec)
values
    ('00:08:45'),
    ('14:18:59.79'),
    ('97:18:59.22'),
    ('98:40:12');


select sq.Id, sq.TimeSec, sq.PreparedTime, 
    cast(parsename(sq.PreparedTime, 4) as bigint) * 3600
    + cast(parsename(sq.PreparedTime, 3) as bigint) * 60
    + cast(parsename(sq.PreparedTime, 2) as bigint)
    + case 
        when cast(parsename(sq.PreparedTime, 1) as bigint) >= 50 
            then 1 
        else 0 
      end
as [TotalSec]
from (
    select t.*, 
            replace(
                        t.TimeSec + 
                        case 
                            when charindex(N'.', t.TimeSec) = 0 
                                then '.0' 
                            else '' 
                        end,
                        ':', 
                        '.'
                    ) as [PreparedTime]
    from @t t
) sq;
```